# Script breaks after the second if statement

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to format an email confirmation from a registration form. If they choose a class that is filled it should produce the else statement otherwise it will show the value that they click on in the form. This works for the first if statement but when I add the second statement it no longer gives me the else statement if the class is full.

```js
if (S1 = sheet.getRange("A6").getValue() && sessionOneLoad6 <= 15){
  var sessionOne = e.values[4];
  }
else {
  var sessionOne = "This section is full, please return to the Enrichment Registration form (link) and choose a new section.";
}
if (S1 = sheet.getRange("A7").getValue() && sessionOneLoad7 <= 15){
  var sessionOne = e.values[4];
  }
else {
  var sessionOne = "This section is full, please return to the Enrichment Registration form (link) and choose a new section.";
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. Use `===` for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` to test for equivalence which is in fact assigning the right hand side to `S1`.

Use `==` to test for value equivalence or `===` for type and value equivalence instead. This will leave the original value of S1 intact for both conditionals.